# Why there is no user interaction between uni-programming and multi-programming systems?

Tags: scheduling, cpu

I was going through my Operating Systems book and in the disadvantages, they wrote that there is no user interaction between the user and computer in uni-programming and multi-programming systems and I asked why? to myself. There was no material or maybe I could not see or understand the idea that why there is no user interaction between the system and the user. I want to understand it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User interaction loosely can be thought of as responding to a user's request while the machine is performing some work. Uni-programmed systems(in the older days) as the name suggests can perform only one task at a time, as only one process could reside in main memory. To handle user inputs, you at least need to have an interrupt mechanism, and the ability to have more than one process in main memory.

Multiprogramming is a term used more often with modern operating systems, which have the ability to handle interrupts and holding more than one process in main memory. If you (hypothetically) take away the ability to handle interrupts, you are left with a batch of processes that would be executed with no user interaction.